# eXistDB - remove user ACE by index....how to get index?

Tags: exist-db

In eXist 4.4 I am setting a user's `rwx` permission in XQuery using `sm:add-user-ace()`. I do not see a corollary 'remove-user-ace', so I assume I have to use `sm:remove-ace($path as xs:anyURI, $index as xs:int)`. However this requires knowing the `$index`. Is there function for getting the `$index` for a combination `$user` and `collection/resource`? (I don't see any at the eXist security [fundocs](http://www.exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://exist-db.org/xquery/securitymanager&location=java:org.exist.xquery.functions.securitymanager.SecurityManagerModule&details=true))

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `sm:get-permissions` function on the URI of the Document or Collection. It will give you an XML document which will show all the ACL entries.

Comment: Thanks. What path does eXist expect for xs:anyURI? If I want to check a document, such as `sm:get-permissions("/db/apps/deheresi/data/MS609-0001.xml")` I'm told that `xs:string is not a subtype of xs:anyURI`. But I also can't pass it a node...

Comment: Nevermind: the answer to my own question is wrapping the URI in `xs:anyURI()`. Therefore `sm:get-permissions(xs:anyURI("/db/apps/deheresi/data/MS609-0001.xml"))`.